# Can't install watch simulator in Xcode

Tags: xcode, watchos

I am trying to install the watch simulator in Xcode but I keep getting this error:

```
Details

Registering simulator runtime with CoreSimulator failed.
Domain: DVTDownloadableErrors
Code: 29
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-11-01 16:19:17 +0000";
}
--
The service used to manage runtime disk images (simdiskimaged) crashed or is not responding
Domain: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError
Code: 410
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.6 (Build 21G115)
Xcode 14.0.1 (21336) (Build 14A400)
Timestamp: 2022-11-01T16:19:17Z
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

1. Delete Xcode
2. Delete ~/Library/Developer folder
3. Restart Mac
4. Install Xcode

Comment: You may not want to delete the entire directory, there's a lot of stuff in there: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104822/260099